# How to do Encryption and Decryption in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to encrypt and decrypt data with sql server using RSA or SHA algorithm rahter than doing it at UI.

Is it possible to do this.

Some Code Snippet will be a great help

Comment: i dont think that's a good idea, doing it in the c# or java or whatever language u use is the best bet.You are unnecessarily putting load on the DB,IMO.

Comment: SHA is a hashing algorithm, don't think you can use it to encrypt

Answer (score 0):

if u need to encrpt only a string (Can't Decrypt these are One way)

u may try

```
HashBytes ('<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } )<algorithm>::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1
```

ref : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx